# Calling a function inside another function in React

Tags: reactjs, function, authentication, ecmascript-6, event-handling

I'm making a Login form which is working, what I want is make that pressing enter makes the same that clicking the submit button. Here's my code:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
      const TOKEN = 'Bearer ' + getToken();
        e.preventDefault();

        const datapost = {
          username : this.state.username,
          password : this.state.password

        }
        let axiosConfig = {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            'Authorization': TOKEN
        }
        };
handleKeyDown(e){
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        console.log("working");
        this.handleSubmit(); 
        }
      } 

<TextField id="filled-basic" onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} label="Contrasenya" type="password" variant="filled" onChange={this.handleChange} name="password" value={this.state.password}/>

  <Button variant="contained" type="submit" onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} color="primary" size="small" onClick={this.handleSubmit} >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is instead of using a `keyDown` event, use a form. If you surround your input and the submit button with a form, your Enter key press will be automatically deemed as submission. Something like this:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <input type="text />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

just change `e.preventDefault();` to `e && e.preventDefault();`

Or if you can use latest language features then you can use optional chaining

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

```
e?.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is, but this might help, if you are getting error

```js
handleKeyDown(e){
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        console.log("working");
        this.handleSubmit(e); // <-- pass e next
    }
}
```

I might help you more if you tell us more